# Can Angular 2 work with WAMP

Tags: angular, wampserver

I have written a website with WAMP & PHP, I am learning Angular 2 to write a web application and want to use MySQL as a database. Just wondering can angular 2 work with WAMP?

Thanks,
   JB

Comment: You only care about if Angular can work with PHP... Windows,  Apache and MySQL have no part in the problem you are asking about

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Angular 2 in PHP application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717556/how-can-i-use-angular-2-in-php-application)

Answer (score 0):

Angular lives on the client. You can use any back-end service with it, PHP and MySQL included.